If consciousness as an external entity is an illusion, does ascribing meaning to the self or detaching from meaning simply vanish?
If consciousness as an entity is a self-indulgent lust for meaning ascribed to our somewhat intuitive belief that the human condition and rational thought underpin being 'conscious', you might see Nihilism as a counterpoint within which meaning and attachment to the conscious self have been abandoned. But if consciousness is simply the act of observation of objective reality through the mind to create subjective experience and being 'conscious' is illusory, Nihilism may be seen as an inherent risk on a mass scale. But if ascribing meaning to the self or not doing so is impossible because the self never existed, would Nihilism be nullified along with our superiority complex over all other creatures?

Consider looking in to Nonduality.

I don't understand 2 parts of the question. Could you elaborate? (1) What is meant by "external entity." To me, it has a vague Star Trek feel, as if consciousness were some substance that could be removed from the brain and stored in a receptacle. Surely that's not what you mean? (2)  "But if consciousness is simply the act of observation of objective reality...to create subjective experience and being 'conscious' is illusory..."  I'm not sure I understand why "subjective experience" would be "illusory." What is experiencing the "subjective experience" if not consciousness?

There are potentially significant interactions between worldviews and one's resulting value systems and life goals, so the premise of your question is very appropriate.
You seem to presume eliminative materialism, in which the idea of a "dual aspect" to the material world is rejected in favor of a solely reductive neurochemistry -- and the idea that we have a self, with attitudes, experiences, and decisions is dismissed as self-deception.
Within the worldview of eliminative materialism, it is very difficult to develop any sort of value system, either for life goals, or for morality -- as pretty much all the aspects of either fall in the bucket of "this is self-deception".
However, nihilism and despair would also be a value system and an attitude, and therefore not real/justifiable.  Same with any sense of superiority over other creatures OR sympathy/empathy/affection for them.  Basically ALL internality thinking is something that a dedicated eliminativist will dismiss.  The most famous eliminative materialists, Patricia and Paul Churchland, seem to have put effort into living by their philosophy, and have provided some very peculiar examples of how they converse in private in some of their books.  They do not reference feelings, goals, etc, but use solely neural state language.
I at least think that very few people have the mental self-discipline to convince themselves they have no internal states, so the self-brainwashing that they Churchland's seem to have accomplished would be a a rare anomaly if their theory of mind were widely accepted as true.  I would expect the denial of what one experiences directly, day in and day out, would instead create unimaginable stress for most people, and yes, lead to an explosion of nihilist thinking.
However, there are multiple competing views about consciousness even among reductive materialists.  It is much more common for materialists to admit that consciousness exists, and assert it is either identical to neurology, or a processing function -- OR that it is emergent from one or the other.  Both Identity Theories and Emergentist theories of materialist consciousness still have problems with both agency and values, but they produce far less psychological stress because they deny far less of our primary experience.  Plus selfhood and agency can be described in Identity Theory terms, rather than denied.
And dual aspect materialists have even more ability to accommodate selfhood, agency and values.
"More ability" still may not be sufficient ability, as Charles Taylor spells out in A Secular Age.  Where a value is in space, and what the mass is of a self, or a decision, are still difficult questions even for more flexible versions of materialism.  Taylor notes that sociologically there is a common phenomenon of both the religious losing their faith under life stresses (due to evidence problems for religious worldviews), and materialists converting to religions worldviews under similar life stresses, due to their desire for a value-centered worldview.

I see no reason to think consciousness being an "external entity" would itself have any impact on life having meaning.
That property by itself doesn't say much about meaning. There is seemingly equal meaning with a purely physical consciousness as there is with a non-physical consciousness that lasts as long as a physical consciousness would (i.e. from when you're born until you're physical body dies).
One would need to add additional properties to affect meaning. If we add in, for example, there being some eternal life, then there remains an eternity of experiences, which would make this life much less meaningful (apart from meeting whatever criteria to get the "best" eternal life, which would be the most important thing one can possibly do). This life would be a negligible spec on an eternal timescale. But that's not entirely true either - we are here, now, experiencing what we're experiencing, and we've only experienced this one life thus far. So our current experiences are certainly extremely meaningful to our present selves (which is a huge problem for e.g. apologetics that try to dismiss Earthly suffering as paling in comparison to eternity).
Meanwhile, our consciousness ending with the death of our physical body means life is as meaningful as it could possibly be. It's not only extremely meaningful to our present selves, but there is no broader context that could even be said to diminish its meaning. There is nothing more important. This is all you've got. The best you can do is make the most of it. This is also all that anyone else has got, which makes it that much more important to help others, for otherwise, the only life they have might be a life of suffering, which would be a tragedy.
Consciousness being physical doesn't mean "the self" doesn't exist. It just means the self is physical. "I think, therefore I am". You exist, you experience the things you experience, regardless of the metaphysical substrate word salad that underpins consciousness. Although there are certainly people with some illusions about consciousness being non-physical.
As for "our superiority complex over all other creatures"... there probably would be a lot of benefit in toning that down. Most of society has accepted that it's bad for people to e.g. think they're better than other races, or to think they're better than other sexes, but there is still a lot of objection to extending that idea to other species. It would seem naïve to think these things are entirely distinct, that one doesn't affect the other. Although as a practical matter, it would probably still make sense to prioritise our own species above others, like how one might prioritise one's family above others (but not to prioritise them so far above that you kill and eat your neighbour because you like how they taste).

Consciousness is that which is aware of its own existence regardless of objectivity.  But since there is somewhere where consciousness must be, it must be in something, i.e. a world.

If the 'cogito sum' is to serve as the point of departure for the
existential analytic of Dasein, then it needs to be turned around, and
furthermore its content needs new ontologico-phenomenal confirmation.
The 'sum' is then asserted first, and indeed in the sense that "I am
in a world".
B&T
211

On the basis of the world the cogito (Dasein) is able to "break into space" and discern objects there.

Only on the basis of its ecstatico-horizonal temporality is it possible for Dasein to break into space. The world is not
present-at-hand in space; yet only within a world does space let
itself be discovered. B&T 421

(This is written up in more detail in a StackExchange answer here: Heidegger made analytic?)
So all things discerned in the world are objective, including one's own thoughts if they are tangible and not unconscious.
OP: "But if consciousness is simply the act of observation of objective reality through the mind to create subjective experience and being 'conscious' is illusory, ..."
Aware understanding is partly unconscious and conscious. The conscious parts are part of objective reality. For example the colour of my coffee mug is in my mind and on the table.  However, unconscious consciousness is invisible and indeterminate.  Nevertheless it is not an illusion, for that would be to mistake it for something else.
